# using get to retrieve value in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve the information from a table to another using the GET function. but it's not working. please, what am i doing wrong?.

```html
  <td><?php echo $row['count(*)']; ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(basic)'],2); ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(hmo)'],2); ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(dha)'],2); ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(tax)'],2); ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(netpay)'],2); ?></td>
        <td><a href="view_payroll_month.php?month=<?php echo $row['year(date)'];?>"><?php echo $row['year(date)'];?></a> </td>
      </tr><?php }?>
```

the second page i want the the result to show in

```html
$year = $_GET['year'];


$qry = "SELECT count(*), sum(basic), sum(hmo), sum(pension), sum(dha), sum(tax), sum(netpay), month(date) FROM salary WHERE year(date) ='$year' GROUP BY month(date)";
$run = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());


<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)) {?>

 
  <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['count(*)']; ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(basic)'],2); ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(hmo)'],2); ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(dha)'],2); ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(tax)'],2); ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(netpay)'],2); ?></td>
        <td><a href="view_month.php?month=<?php echo $row['month(date)'];?>"><?php echo $row['month(date)'];?></a> </td>
      </tr><?php }?>
```

Comment: you forget to add the year= request in your a href

Comment: you are passing "month" in params and fetching "year" in get method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

```
<td><?php echo $row['count(*)']; ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(basic)'],2); ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(hmo)'],2); ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(dha)'],2); ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(tax)'],2); ?></td>
        <td>N<?php echo number_format($row['sum(netpay)'],2); ?></td>
        <td><a href="view_payroll_month.php?year=<?php echo $row['year(date)'];?>">><?php echo $row['year(date)'];?></a> </td>
        </tr><?php }?>
```

Reason: You were tried to pass value in month inside href. And tried to retrieve from get year parameter. Just change from month to year inside href. And you could able to retrieve year now. name parameter must to equal to get name parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is the URL in your link:

```
view_payroll_month.php?month=...
```

The query string parameter is called `month`.  But you try to fetch a value called `year`:

```
$_GET['year']
```

Query string and/or form values are key/value pairs.  The values are uniquely identified by the keys (names) with which they're associated.  So you need to either:

- Fetch the value by `month` instead of `year`, or
- Pass the value `year` instead of `month`, or
- Pass the value `year` in addition to `month`.

Something like this:

```
<a href="view_payroll_month.php?month=<?php echo $row['month(date)']; ?>&year=<?php echo $row['year(date)']; ?>">
```